# "behind the open door are hidden several differences". Is this grammatically correct? (Inversion+adverbial phrase of location+be verb)

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

> Behind the open door are hidden several differences.

This seems to be an inversion of the sentence

> Several differences are hidden behind the open door.

Both sound intuitively correct, but the former inverted sentence does not fit the general inversion pattern of 'adverbial phrase + verb + subject', since it also contains the complement, 'hidden'.

Is there an inversion sentence pattern that I'm missing? Or is the former sentence just plain wrong?

Comment: No, it's fine. _Hidden behind the open door are..._ would be possible as well.

Comment: It's an example of subject-dependent inversion. Here, the inversion involves the subject "several differences" and the locative complement "behind the open door", This type of inversion puts the subject in final position, where it receives greater phonological prominence.

Comment: [X] [are hidden] [somewhere]; _inversion_: [somewhere] [are hidden] [X]. You should treat the verb _are hidden_ as one constituent for analysis.

Comment: The expression "are hidden" is not here a constituent. The fact that it remains static in the inversion process is immaterial.

Comment: @BillJ: Could you provide a detailed answer, please? Would be of great help to many of us learners here.

Comment: @BillJ Grammarians consider the "verb phrase" to be a constituent of the clause. It should be said that "hidden" is the adjective, not the past participle.

Comment: @LPH "are hidden" is not the VP here. The VPs here are "are hidden behind the open door" / "are hidden several differences". The VPs consist of two constituents, the predicator "are" and the AdjP "hidden behind the open door" / "hidden several differences".

Comment: @BillJ I think that you go by a different definition of "verb phrase" (CoGEL: The constituents which function as elements of clause structure are either phrases or subordinate clauses […] Verb phrases are headed as to the extent that they are composed of two kinds of element, auxiliaries and main verb […]).

Comment: @LPH A VP consists of a predicator (verb) and its dependents (if any), such as complements and adjuncts. But this is not relevant to the OP's question which is about inversion, so don't go off-topic.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the notion of several 'differences' being hidden.

Comment: Wouldn't they be more hidden by a closed door? How does an open door 'hide' anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1] *Behind the open door are hidden several differences.*

[2] *Several differences are hidden behind the open door.*

[1] is a straightforward example of subject-dependent inversion, while [2] is the basic version.

The inversion involves the subject "several differences" and the complement "behind the open door", which have swapped places in [1].

This type of inversion puts the subject in final position and the complement in front position, where it typically serves as a link to the preceding discourse.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Nate, the orders of words in English are not fully prescribed by a set of rules.  Some orders create confusion as to meaning or fail to convey a clear meaning at all.

> Behind the several differences the open door are hidden

Here there is an obvious mistake:  the main verb is plural where it should be singular.  Even when this 'mistake' is corrected and *are* is replaced by *is*, or *door* is replaced by *doors*, the 'grammatically correct sentence makes no immediate logical or empirical sense.

But your alternatives all make perfectly good sense.  And you are right to think that, if we are looking at it in terms of how sample sentences are usually set out in text books for learners of the English language, your version would be the standard version.  Except, of course that this particular sentence is more literary than the type that would appear in English language text book, at least at the earlier stages.

Some variations are absolutely wrong, of course.  You cannot reverse subject and predicate.

> A car was run over by a stray dog.

This is perfectly grammatical, of course.  Simply, we know it cannot be what the news reader meant to say.  In the case of your sentences, the order depends on what is being emphasised.  The 'open door', is obviously a metaphorical reference to something like a negotiation between two parties.  The 'open door' suggests that outward willingness on the part of one or possibly both parties.  The point of the sentence is that despite the apparent willingness 'several differences'  matters may not be a be as easy as they seem.

The order creates suspense by making us wait for the 'punch line'.  "Behind the open door" <"What's going on behind it?", we are thinking>.  "... are hidden" <"**what**?, come on, get on with it!" "...several differences."  This, in turn, makes us alert and ready for something very important.

So the rhetorical effect is to build tension towards a climax.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an inversion sentence pattern that I'm missing?

*Behind the open door are hidden several differences* is a sentence in the causative passive:

*“Prior to the illusion taking place, the room is arranged to suit the illusionist and behind the open door are hidden several differences”*, which can be restated as = *the illusionist arranges for several differences to be hidden behind the open door by his assistant.*

The construction is fronted by a locative adverbial – *“Behind the open door”*. The locative adverbial allows the subject verb inversion although in current Modern English this is not that common, c.f. *"In the forest lived a hermit." / "Dearly do I love her."*

Comment: I'd say it's subject-dependent inversion, not subject-verb inversion.